# How to put one column of an Excel sheet, into another one, based on the same unique identifier

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two sheets in Excel. One sheet with these column names:

`Student ID, Telephone Number, City, Address, Preference 1, Preference 2`

`Entry date, Student ID, City, Availability, Preference 1, Preference 2`

So, in the first sheet, Preference 1 and 2 are blank. The Student ID's are not in the same order in sheet 2 as in sheet 1. I need to put Preference 1 and 2 from sheet 2 in sheet 1, based on the student ID. How can I do that?

I tried to do it manually, but this takes a lot of work so I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this that I do not know of. I am new to Excel so I don't know about any formulas or where to put those formulas. I have looked at other topics in Stackoverflow too, but these were more difficult than my problem and the solutions seemed difficult as well (I didn't understand them). If someone knows a solution, then please say so!

Comment: Are Student IDs in the same order on both sheets, or mixed up? if the same, you can do a copy; if different you need a Lookup.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes they are in different orders. I have looked up the Lookup, but this is a formula for one sheet only right? Mine are in two sheets

Comment: You can make a formula that looks up values in another sheet, bear with and let me put it into an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I have assumed that

- your sheets are named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`,
- The column names you've given are in order and start in column A
- Row 1 contains column headers, data starts from Row 2

If the above is true, in Sheet1 Cell E2 (the first blank cell in 'Preference 1') type:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet2'!B:F, 4, FALSE)
```

And in the cell next to that type the same, but replace the `4` with a `5`.
The cells should auto-populate with the relevant data.

Then, select both of those cells you've just filled in so that they get a green outline showing they're selected, and double-click the little square at the bottom-right of the green outline to flash-fill that formula down your dataset.

(obviously if any of my assumptions were wrong, you'll need to edit the process and/or formula accordingly)

Comment: It doesn't fill anything in.. Maybe because many rows in the Preference 1 column are blank?

Comment: Could you share a `One-Drive` link in the comments, because the above formula is a working formula only, it works, if there is something in your workbook we wont be able to understand,